# Core class reading input data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a base controller that needs to log an action any time post data is received. Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to tell if post data is received, `$this->input` isn't showing any signs of post data.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        var_dump($this->router->fetch_class()); // Requested class
        var_dump($this->router->fetch_method()); // Requested method

        // None of the below shows post data
        var_dump($this->input->post());
        var_dump($_SERVER);
        var_dump($this->input);
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
}
?>
```

The data isn't really necessary, just need to know that post data was sent.

Comment: Is there POST data to see? are you sending a POST request while you're dumping the ouput? Try `var_dump($this->input->post()); die();`

Comment: @Kisaragi The code shows that I'm trying to dump the output. I know the post data is sending, i'm updating entries in the db. Just trying to log the action in extended core controllers.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, however, if  another request proceeds your request that has the post data, then `input->post()` would be empty. This is why I suggested you a die statement after you've posted. Otherwise, the above should work.

Comment: @Kisaragi you're onto it, it was a redirect after entry updating that caused the input data to show empty.